# Trying to get recent External Hard Drive name (with spaces) via terminal

Tags: macos, bash, shell, mount, hard-drive

I've been using this command to retrieve recent hard drive connected to mac:

```
mount | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f3
```

Problem is that if a drive has spaces, then it only grabs the first word of that external harddrive. **How can I get the whole name of the drive, whether it has one word or spaces with many words**?

Answer (score 1):

The output of `mount` (OSX) is:

```
<device_path> on <mount_point> (<type>,<options_list>)
```

So the alternative approach is to extract everything before the word `on` excluding the preceeding space (or to remove the space, the word `on` and everything else to the end of line):

```
mount | tail -1 | sed 's/ on .* ([^)]*)$//'
```

Although, based on your command, you seem to be interested in the mount point, not the device name. In that case, it becomes "extract the characters between `on` and `type` excluding leading and trailing spaces:

```
mount | tail -1 | sed '/^.* on \(.*\) ([^)]*)$/\1/'
```

The `([^)]*)` component avoids matching problems in corner cases (where the device name or mountpoint contains space, `on`, space).

Comment: I think `^` and `$` in the `s` command are useless since both `.*` are greedy.

Comment: @Kenavoz: you are right, force of habit. Anyway, adapted the answer to OSX output and changed the expression somewhat to cover the edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
mount | tail -1 | sed -e "s/^[^/]*\(.*\) type .*$/\1/g"
```